# writing a program for finding nth prime term to find 10001st prime

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, primes

i have actually written my nth term function, which takes in n and compiles all prime numbers in the list "primes", and return the indexed position -1 of primes which is 10001st prime:
please if someone can improve my code or write a better code for this problem.

```
def nthprime(n):
    primes = [2]
    attempt = 3
    while len(primes) < n:    # it runs until the len of primes is greater or equal to n
        if all(attempt % prime != 0 for prime in primes):
            primes.append(attempt)
        attempt += 2
        
        break
    return primes[-1]
print(nthprime(10001))
```

thanks in advance for Help :)

Comment: so general comments: you should be more confident in your code! it looks awesome actually - also, what exactly is the question here?  are you looking for general improvements? or are you getting an error from the python interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine, and quite pythonic :)

The algorithm you are implementing could be optimized, though, because you don't need to check every prime number as a factor for the new attempted number; for example numbers ending in a '5' are trivially not prime (I'm sure you can see why).

I suggest you check out the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which is a famous prime-number sieve, i.e. an algorithm to find all the primes up to a certain number. I have linked the Wikipedia here, and from there you should also be able to find some information on more modern sieves, although they are all based on the same principle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

James from mCoding also made some great videos about implementing this in Python, and showed how you could scale these ideas up to get some really big lists of primes, so if you want some inspiration on how to improve your code, these would be a great place to start:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JA_YrFwE1hc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwM8PGBYazM

Good luck!